# JavaScript decorators example not working

Tags: javascript, object, decorator, babeljs

I'm trying to learn decorators in javascript. I'm trying to get a small example running for this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.e29zkn36i). This logs `undefined`, and I'm not sure why.

```
function superhero(target) {
  target.isSuperhero = true
  target.power = 'flight'
}

@superhero
class MySuperHero { }

let superman = new MySuperHero()

console.log(superman.power) // should log flight
```

And when I do this I get the error `You have trailing decorators with no method`

```
class MySuperHero {
  @superhero
}
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.21",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "syntax-decorators",
      "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The decorated value will not appear on the instance. Try logging `MySuperHero.isSuperhero`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @torazaburo, this works.

```
function superhero(target) {
  target.isSuperhero = true
  target.power = 'flight'
}

@superhero
class MySuperHero {

}

console.log(MySuperHero.power) // "flight"
```

Answer (score 0):

The decorated value will not appear on the instance. Try logging MySuperHero.isSuperhero.